# using case in a sql query is not returning the correct results

Tags: sql

in my sql query - one line as listen below returns me a varchar - I need to use a case statement (i think case is the way to go) so that when AC.Type_Name = 'None' Then I need to store '' as TypeName, not the word none. Anyone know the most simple way to do this? Thank you.

```
AC.Type_Name As TypeName,
```

this is used in part of a stored procedure - it isn't stored to a table. It is for use with a asp.net application. I could store the results to a temporary table, then use update as said below by redfilter, then return the temp table but I was looking for the quickest way possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that your code reference above refers to a field in the select clause of a stored procedure.  If that's the case, you should be able to modify it as follows:

```
(case when AC.Type_Name = 'None' then '' else AC.Type_Name end) as TypeName
```

This statement will return a column called TypeName that will contain the value of AC.Type_Name unless the value of AC.Type_Name is 'None', in which case it will return it as an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

```
update MyTable
set Type_Name = case when @input = 'None' then '' else @input end
where ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this is used in part of a stored procedure - it isn't stored to a table. It is for use with a asp.net application. I could store the results to a temporary table, do this, then return the temp table but I was looking for the quickest way possible.

Comment: I think this reply was simply due to the lack of context in the original post. The concept is spot on.  SELECT CASE WHEN AC.Type_Name = 'None' THEN '' ELSE AC.TypeName END AS TypeName

Comment: @njj56 Your question says *I need to store '' as TypeName* - that implies `INSERT` or `UPDATE`, not `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to use the 'if()' function.

SELECT IF(AC.Type_Name = 'None', '', AC.TypeName) FROM ....